# How to add assignments to EC2 host /etc/fstab when identifiers are not unique?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, fstab

I have volumes connected to an AWS EC2 instance running Linux and would like one of them to be mounted as root `/` on reboot.

One option is to put the device UUID into the host's `/etc/fstab` entry.

However, I seem to have a situation where all the volumes visible to me have the same UUIDs, e.g.:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/xvda1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="bbf64c6d-bc15-4ae0-aa4c-608fd9820d1234" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9f3e4931-01"
/dev/xvdf1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="bbf64c6d-bc15-4ae0-aa4c-608fd9820d1234" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9f3e4931-01"
/dev/xvdg1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="bbf64c6d-bc15-4ae0-aa4c-608fd9820d1234" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9f3e4931-01"
/dev/xvdh1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="bbf64c6d-bc15-4ae0-aa4c-608fd9820d1234" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9f3e4931-01"
```

The current entry in `/etc/fstab` uses the `LABEL` key, which is also identical for these four devices.

If it is not safe to use the device path, as mentioned in Amazon's documentation, what identifier can I use that will uniquely and reliably select the same and correct device on boot?

Or can I change the identifiers that these devices are using, such that I can make them unique for purposes of assignment in `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the labels or UUIDs with `tune2fs -L` or `tune2fs -U`. See [man tune2fs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs).